# Sorting a Python list of numbers without knowing their values, but only their relationships among each other

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, graph

I have a list of numbers which I can't really know their real values. Let's say `list = [a,b,c,d]` . But I have information about how they relate to each other:

```
a > b
b > d
d > c
```

Therefore I can infer that list sorted in descending order is `[ a, b, d, c]`.

Another more complicated example

```
relationships =
 - g > b
 - d > c > a
 - d > g
 - f > e > a
 - f > e > d
```

In this case we have multiple possible answers

```
            Result: 
  [ [f, e, d, c, a, g, b],
    [f, e, d, g, c, a, b],
    [f, e, d, g, c, b, a],
  ... ]
```

just to name a few

I want the function to return me exactly that: a list of all possible answers. The relationships is a list of lists, where each list representes the relationship of the sorting in descending order. For example `relationships = [[a,b],[b,c]]` tells me that "a > b" and "b > c" . The inner lists inside relationships don't have to be necessarily of the same size. In case of an invalid/impossible input the algorithm should thrown an error. For example:

`relationships = [[a,b],[b,c],[c,a]` is an impossible case

What's the best approach for this that is also efficient ? I was thinking about using graphs theory where the graphs cannot be acyclic. For example  A -> B means Node A goes to B meaning A > B , therefore  B -> A cannot exist. Somehow like a binary tree, but in this case instead of allowing 2 child per node we can only allow 1.

Is that a good idea to start on this or does anyone have any better idea on how to approach this?

Comment: This is called a "topological sort".  I see lots of Python implementations out there, although I don't know if any support your "all possible answers" requirement - a typical application of toposort only needs a single answer.

Comment: Here's a related answer on [Partial Order Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620100/partial-order-sorting) which substantiates you're on the right track and provides additional information and links such as [Python Topological Sort](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577413-topological-sort/) software may be useful for your task.

Comment: oh thanks guys! Knowing the term for it makes a whole world of difference. That's exactly it. I'll come later with my own implementation for this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 ideas to understand this.

First is topological sorting via Kahn's algorithm.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm for a description.  I am walking through all of the way to generate a topological sort by that algorithm, and `yield`ing each one.

The second is stack based programming.  Think Forth, or RPN.  The idea is that I have a stack of actions.  At each step I take the top action off of the `todo` list and do it.  If I add items onto the `todo` list, then that is like having recursive calls.  In my case the actions are to `choose` (try all choices that make sense), `add` (add an element to the sorted list and do bookkeeping), `remove` (remove an element from the sorted list and do bookkeeping) and `try` (schedule the actions add/choose/remove - but placed in the opposite order because stack).

The third is generators.  I just `yield` multiple times and then continue from where I was.  This can be looped over, turned into a list, etc.

Here is the code.

```
def topological_sorts (descending_chains):
    arrive_to = {}
    outstanding_arrivals = {}
    for chain in descending_chains:
        for x in chain:
            if x not in arrive_to:
                arrive_to[x] = set([])
                outstanding_arrivals[x] = 0
        for i in range(1, len(chain)):
            arrive_to[chain[i-1]].add(chain[i])

    for item in arrive_to:
        for x in arrive_to[item]:
            outstanding_arrivals[x] += 1

    todo = [['choose', None]]
    sorted_items = []
    chosen = set([])
    items = [x for x in arrive_to]
    while len(todo):
        action, item = todo.pop()
        if action == 'choose':
            choices = []
            for x in outstanding_arrivals:
                if x not in chosen and 0 == outstanding_arrivals[x]:
                    choices.append(x)
            if 0 == len(choices):
                if len(sorted_items) == len(items):
                    yield sorted_items
                else:
                    print((choices, outstanding_arrivals, sorted_items))
                    break
            else:
                for item in choices:
                    todo.append(['try', item])
        elif action == 'try':
            chosen.add(item)
            sorted_items.append(item)
            todo.append(['remove', item])
            todo.append(['choose', None])
            todo.append(['add', item])
        elif action == 'add':
            chosen.add(item)
            for x in arrive_to[item]:
                outstanding_arrivals[x] -= 1
        elif action == 'remove':
            chosen.remove(item)
            sorted_items.pop()
            for x in arrive_to[item]:
                outstanding_arrivals[x] += 1
        else:
            yield ('todo:', action, item)
```

and here is how to use it for your second example.

```
for sort in topological_sorts([
        ['g', 'b'],
        ['d', 'c', 'a'],
        ['d', 'g'],
        ['f', 'e', 'a'],
        ['f', 'e', 'd']]):
    print(sort)
```

Comment: I wish I could give 100 likes to this answer. This works and it is so elegant. Thank you so much. I wasn't aware on the concept of generators. Really cool stuff. So I can basically make a function behave like an iterator then?

Comment: @RafaelSantos Exactly.  You can construct iterators by hand in Python, but simply having a function with `yield` and no `return` does all of the bookkeeping for you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Python code for Topological sort on site Rosetta Code [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python).

The input is a dict mapping nodes to the set of nodes it depends on, (in your case, nodes they are "greater than"). use the following to represent your example dependencies:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g = 'abcdefg'  # For ease of use
data = {c:a, d:'cag', e:'ad', f:'ead', g:b}  # <node>:<is_greater_than>
dat = {key: set(val) for key, val in data.items()}
print ('\n'.join( toposort2(dat) ))
```

The correct output is the following, where nodes on the same line can appear in any order before nodes from other lines above it:

```
a b
c g
d
e
f
```

**Note** your solution you give to your example is wrong in that you cannot have f,e,d then followed immediately by **b**; it must by c or g (in any order); then a or b (in any order).