# Sort a list based on order of subset of items in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Assuming a list of variables `{a,b,c,d,e}` and based on some values their order should be `c > b > d > e > a`. What I have is a ordered subset of list, e.g:

`b > d > a`

`c > e`

`b > e > a`

`c > b > a` and so on.

Using the order of subset of lists, how can I arrive at full order of list. If a comparison of any 2 element doesn't exist, their respective order will not matter e.g. `c > b > d = e > a` if no comparison of `d` & `e` exist.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620100/partial-order-sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider each ordered subset as defining directed edges in a graph (the variables are the vertices), so for example, b>d>a defines edges b->d and d->a, and then [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the resulted graph.

Comment: See also: https://pypi.org/project/toposort/ & https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-topological-sorting/

Answer (score 0):

Solving the above problem, Follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Assign a unique integer to each character... for which I have used a dictionary.

**Step 2:** Then make comparisons as a list.

**Step 3:** Make a list of values they have in the dictionary...Sort that list and assign the values to the character's comparison list in the same order.

**Step 4:** Follow Step3 again using reset_list to maintain the comparison in the correct order.

At last, by performing the operations you will get the correct order by sorting character by their values in the dictionary.

```
list_alpha = [None,'a','b','c','d','e']
dictionary = dict()

for i in range(1,len(list_alpha)):
    dictionary[list_alpha[i]] = i
    
reset_list = []    
    
n = int(input())
for seq in range(n):
    comparison = input()
    comparison_list = comparison.split(" ")
    reset_list.append(comparison_list)
    index_list = []
    for j in comparison_list:
        index_list.append(dictionary[j])
    index_list.sort()
    for i,j in enumerate(comparison_list):
        dictionary[j] = index_list[i]

for comparison_list in reset_list:
    index_list = []
    for j in comparison_list:
        index_list.append(dictionary[j])
    index_list.sort()
    for i,j in enumerate(comparison_list):
        dictionary[j] = index_list[i]
        
        
tp = []
for i,j in dictionary.items():
    tp.append((i,j))
tp.sort(key = lambda x : (x[1]))

for i,j in tp:
    print(i)
```

**Input:**

```
4

b d a

c e

b e a

c b a
```

**Output:**

```
c

b

d

e

a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a suitable comparison function, you ought to be able to use this more or less directly with python's builtin `list.sort` (or `sorted`) via `cmp_to_key` to do this sorting *(although I suggest this with the caveat that I might be missing some radically different and more efficient solution)*.

For example:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def compare(x, y):

    orders = [['b', 'd', 'a'],
              ['c', 'e'],
              ['b', 'e', 'a'],
              ['c', 'b', 'a']]

    for order in orders:
        if x in order and y in order:
            if order.index(x) > order.index(y):
                return 1
            else:
                return -1
    return 0


print(sorted(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             key=cmp_to_key(compare)))
```

This gives:

```
['c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'a']
```

Here is a more efficient version that uses sets for inclusion testing, although it relies on the items being hashable:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

orders = [['b', 'd', 'a'],
          ['c', 'e'],
          ['b', 'e', 'a'],
          ['c', 'b', 'a']]

order_pairs = [(set(order), order) for order in orders]


def compare(x, y):
    for order_set, order in order_pairs:
        if x in order_set and y in order_set:
            if order.index(x) > order.index(y):
                return 1
            else:
                return -1
    return 0


print(sorted(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             key=cmp_to_key(compare)))
```

Comment: I think I have solved it using the same approach as mentioned by you... without using functools module. Could you confirm it...?

Comment: @YashShah Sorry, I have not looked at your algorithm in detail.